# How to save emails in an email list on SendGrid using Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, email, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I'm working on a functionality where once a user signs up for an account, he will start getting a series of email throughout a time period (email drips).

I'm using Laravel. I need to grab the email on sign up and **save it on an email list on SendGrid**. But I don't find this on the `sendgrid/sendgrid-php` package's docs.

So, would you please tell me how I may implement this?

Answer (score 1):

It [can be done](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/contacts/add-or-update-a-contact) with the sendgrid-php package:

```
use SendGrid;

$api = new SendGrid(YOUR_API_KEY);
$contacts = [
    [
        'email' => "email@something",
        'address_line_1' => '',
        'city' => '',
        'country' => '',
        'first_name' => '',
        'last_name' => '',
        etc....
    ]
]
$request_body = [
    'contacts' => $contacts
];

$response = $api->client->marketing()->contacts()->put($request_body);
if($response->statusCode() !== 202) {
    // error has occured
}
```